# He brought a bag for someone to take (it)

Tags: infinitives

I have been thinking about the sentence "He brought a bag for someone to take (it)" because if I used "so that", I think "it" would be required.
"He brought a bag so that someone can take it". I have not been able to find any information explaining what happens when the noun right before *for* corresponds to the complement of the infinitive, at least as a grammatical argument.

Any advice is much appreciated!

Comment: When it's right before, it's spelled out. The *it* is only required when making a second reference to the subject later in the sentence (as you do with *so that …*). Depending how you look at it, *a bag for someone to take* is acting as a noun *(noun phrase)* which is the object of *He brought …*. The *so that …* form is rather different; it’s explaining *the motive behind the bringing*, rather than *the purpose of the bag*. The end result is the same, but how you get there is very different.

Answer (score 0):

It's a relative clause, as in "He brought a bag that was filled with cookies." Respectively, the clauses "that was filled with cookies" and "for someone to take" qualify "bag". English often elides the "that", as in "He brought a bag filled with cookies"; conversely, think of your sentence as an elided version of "He brought a bag that was for someone to take".